# sicstus prolog move predicate

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

I have a list that I want to manipulate in Prolog according to this description:

Original list:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Moving C , I can have two results (from top-right to top-left and from top-right to bottom):

```
CAB          ABF
DEF    or    DEI
GHI          GHC
```

Moving G from the original list, I can also have two results (from bottom-left to top-left or from bottom-left to bottom-right)

```
GBC           ABC
AEF     or    DEF
DHI           HIG
```

Moving D from the original list, I can  have three  results (from from middle-left to top-left, from middle-left to bottom-left and from middle-left to middle-right):

```
DBC             ABC             ABC
AEF     or      GEF      or     EFD
GHI             DHI             GHI
```

The idea here is that, whenever I take an element (let's call it current element) and place it to a new position, I will push other elements of a sub-list, so that the old neighbor of my current element occupies the old position of the current element. The old neighbor old position will hold another element which is being replaced by the current element. In a whole, since every element belongs to two lists , column list and row list, by moving one element and placing to another position will do two actions: rotating one list and replacing in another list one element by the current element I am moving.
Note that the very-middle element (for example E in the original list) cannot be the current element but it can have a new location when it's pushed.
The only elements allowed to be the "current element" (from original list) are A,B,C,D,F,G,H and I.

So far, my efforts to resolve this problem are as follow. I have created a predicate which can rotate elements of a list:

```
rotate([],_,[]) :- !.
rotate(L1,N,L2) :-
    length(L1,NL1),
    N1 is N mod NL1,
    split(L1,N1,S1,S2),
    append(S2,S1,L2).

split(L,0,[],L).
split([X|Xs],N,[X|Ys],Zs) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    split(Xs,N1,Ys,Zs).
```

But this predicate gives me only a small part of the solution I want. It works only with elements which are in the four corners of the original list I want to manipulate. This does not work with the elements located in the middle-left or middle-right.

```
| ?- rotate([a,b,c,d,e],1,X).
 X = [b,c,d,e,a] ? 
 yes [This result if fine for me]

| ?- rotate([a,b,c,d,e],-1,X).
 X = [e,a,b,c,d] ? 
yes (This one is also fine)

| ?- rotate([a,b,c,d,e],2,X).
X = [c,d,e,a,b] ?
yes (This is not fine because I expect X = [a,c,d,e,b])
```

Another challenge with this problem, is that I am manipulating two lists at the same time: one list which constitutes a column and the second list which constitutes a row.

Comment: I just did an edition of the post to add my efforts with rotate predicate code.